# What Feature Profile does NServiceBus.Host.Exe run under by default?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

There are a number of feature profiles:

Master,
Distributor,
Worker,
PerformanceCounters.

If I dont specify a Feature profile  switch to NServiceBus.Host.exe like below (Where I have passed the Production host profile)

```
NServiceBus.Host.exe NServiceBus.Production
```

What am I actually running?    Also If  I run under Distributor (bizarrely) I can get the Endpoint to do work, when it shouldn't be?

Comment: var isDistributorEnabled = busConfiguration
    .GetSettings()
    .GetOrDefault<bool>(typeof(Distributor).FullName);

Comment: var isDistributorEnabled = SettingsHolder.GetOrDefault<bool>("Distributor.Enabled"); NSB4

Comment: What version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

An NServiceBus Endpoint  will run as an Distributor (bear with me)  with an embedded Worker which, I can't quite make out from the NSB docs, but is equivalent to running as a Master  (which is a Distributor and a Worker - but perhaps with a few more things turned on - Gateway etc? )

So specifying explicitly this behaviour for NServiceBus 4.10

Command line switch

- NServiceBus.MSMQMaster

Code

- configure.AsMSMQMasterNode();
- configure.RunMSMQDistributor();

The last line, actually runs as a Distributor and Worker together.

Confusingly, below would run the Endpoint as a Distributor **without** a Worker

Command line switch

- NServiceBus.MSMQDistributor

Code

- configure.RunMSMQDistributor(withWorker:    false);